# Frame layout foreground property is not working in grid view

Tags: android, android-gridview

iam developing an android custom gallery where am using grid view and a framelayout as gridview item(for foreground property for selector). everthing works fine , but it's not drawing it's selected state after scrolling ..

here is my get view method

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final GalleryHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_child_gallery_item, parent, false);
            holder = new GalleryHolder();
            holder.folderThumbnail = (RecyclingImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail); 
            holder.baseLayout = (GalleryFrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.baseItemLayout);
            convertView.setTag(holder);   
        } else          
            holder = (GalleryHolder) convertView.getTag();

        if(mSelections.contains(String.valueOf(position))){
            holder.baseLayout.setSelected(true);
        }
        else{
            holder.baseLayout.setSelected(false)
        }


        if(getGallerytype().equals(GallerySwitcherFragment.IMAGES))
            loadBitmap(GallerySwitcherFragment.IMAGES, 
                    Long.valueOf(mFiles.get(position).getThumbnailData()), holder.folderThumbnail);
        else
            loadBitmap(GallerySwitcherFragment.VIDEOS, 
                    Long.valueOf(mFiles.get(position).getThumbnailData()),holder.folderThumbnail);



        holder.baseLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                holder.baseLayout.setChecked(true); 
                mController.toggleActionBarItems(true);
                return true;
            }
        });

        holder.baseLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isMultiSelectionEnabled){
                    if(mSelections.contains(String.valueOf(position)))
                        mSelections.remove(String.valueOf(position));
                    else
                        mSelections.add(String.valueOf(position));


                }
                else
                    return;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

and here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sams.customcomponents.GalleryFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="119dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:id="@+id/baseItemLayout"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/gridview_selector" >

    <com.sams.customcomponents.RecyclingImageView android:id="@+id/iv_thumbnail"
        android:contentDescription="@string/iv_content_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black" />

</com.sams.customcomponents.GalleryFrameLayout>
```

here is my selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
          android:drawable="@color/selector_blue"/> <!-- pressed state -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:drawable="@color/selector_blue"/> <!-- focused state -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
          android:drawable="@color/selector_blue"/> <!-- selected state -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/> <!-- default state --> 
</selector>
```